# como solucionar Error tokenizing data

Tags: python, pandas

hola tengo un archivo csv que al leerlo con pandas me salta error

```
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 57 fields in line 305, saw 72
```

al investigar sobre el error entiendo que es porque alguna o varias lineas tienen mayor numero de columnas que las del header; al verificar manualmente la lista efectivamente encuentro lineas como esta

```
E0,15/05/04,Wolves,Tottenham,0,2,A,0,1,A,S Bennett,18,14,10,12,6,11,5,3,1,1,1,0,2.37,3.3,2.8,2.3,3.25,2.75,2.2,3,2.9,2.2,3.25,2.75,2.3,3.2,3,2.38,3.2,2.62,2.25,3.3,2.62,1.75,1.95,1.8,2,1.75,2.1,0,,,,,,,,,,,
```

alfinal de la linea tiene una serie de ',' la cuestion es que son varias lineas asi y me preguntaba si hay alguna manera para que pandas (python) genere esos espacios con "nan" y asi eliminar posteriormente las columnas?

este es el codigo que tengo

```
import pandas as pd
pl = pd.read_csv("pl.csv", sep=",")
pl.head()
```

edit: ya lo solucione, aunque de una forma poco ortodoxa :) básicamente trate el archivo mediante una importación en microsoft excel y luego realice la limpieza del mismo, de hecho el mismo programa lo facilito todo, saludos